# Gnu Make: how to use the pattern rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this sample (siimplified) makefile

```
all: a a.e b b.e

.SUFFIXES:

a a.e:
    touch $@

b: a
    ln -sf $(notdir $<) $@

b.e: a.e
    ln -sf $(notdir $<) $@

clean:
    rm -f a* b*
```

and it works.

I would like to use `Pattern Rules` as follow:

```
all: a a.e b b.e

.SUFFIXES:

a a.e:
    touch $@

b%: a%
    ln -sf $(notdir $<) $@

clean:
    rm -f a* b*
```

but it fails:

```
$ make
touch a
touch a.e
make: *** No rule to make target 'b', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

I cannot figure out why, and I don't know how to make it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this info from the manual give you your answer:

> The target is a pattern for matching file names; the ‘%’ matches any **nonempty** substring, while other characters match only themselves.

(emphasis added)?